# MPI command on mfc application

Tags: c++, mfc, editcontrol

I'm executing an executable file through cmd while parallel processing. The command I use is

mpiexec -n 2 Solution.exe

I want to run this file in a MFC project. I have a dialogue box like the picture below, when I press the OK button on this dialogue box I want my exe file to run. User will input the filename and number of threads which in the above case is 2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFi9n.png)

Comment: You can call `system()` or `CreateProcess()` when the button is cklicked.

Comment: There is no _picture below_.

Comment: I can't seem to upload it.

Comment: Picture uploaded

Comment: hmmm...What is the question here?

Comment: I run my exe file from the command prompt using the command

Comment: mpiexec -n 2 MKL.exe

Comment: Where MKL is the name of the file and 2 is number of threads. Need to run this when I click the OK button after taking the 2 inputs in the edit control